# Is there text/code editor that can highlight PHP tags?

Tags: php, android, editor

I have tried few and they only highlight HTML/Javascript even though they offer shortcuts for php tags they dont have PHP highlighting. someone knows of one that highlights php?

P.S. dont get me wrong i am not going to program on phone, just in case i need to fix error or two on the go...

Comment: Here's another one to try. The site states "Dymanic syntax highlighting". http://www.nusphere.com/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try Eclipse. Here's a link for the php version of Eclipse:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliosr

Answer (score 2):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) - supports most languages

Answer (score 0):

You can use DroidEdit (disclaimer: I'm the developer): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.droidedit

Another alternative is Jota: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.sblo.pandora.jota

For Java, Aide is a great editor that even allows to build your own apk: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui

All of them work great in your phone but work better if you have an external keyboard or a Transformer Prime.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my app - [Android Web Developer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kidinov.awd). It contains a lot features, e.g.:

- Support all major web languages and formats: PHP, JavaScript, CSS, HTML
- A lot of ways to reach your project ( FTP, FTPS, SFTP, WEBDav and growing)
- Code highlighting
- Code completion
- Error checking
- Hardware keyboard support (e.g hotkeys)
- Code beautifying with one click
- Tablet ready UI
- Line numbering
- Quick preview of your page
- Highlighting the current line
- Search and replace with regular expressions
- Unlimited Undo/redo
- Full screen mode
- Recent projects
- Periodical autosaving
- Rename/create/delete/copy-paste files inside you project

I hope it will be useful for you

[image]